# (Why) are mariachis considered wimpy (or are they (not))?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos

"Ser [muy] mariachi" means, according to "Smart Spanish for Tontos Americanos", ["To be a wimp."](https://books.google.com/books?id=Apwu_oW3770C&pg=PT218&lpg=PT218&dq=ser+mariachi+Smart+Spanish&source=bl&ots=SdCHDrSN2q&sig=lgnXfJYRYGt7PIAw3fUyHJfCWns&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z_6JVfbVHMH7-AGZko3ICA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ser%20mariachi%20Smart%20Spanish&f=false)

Why? Is Mariachi music considered like "elevator music" or what?

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with music at all. In Spain _mariquita_ is another word for _gay_. It's "mild" (milder that _marica_ at least...), but of course it is an insult with nasty connotations. Besides _gay_ it can also mean "weak", "wimp", etc. I wonder if the similitude of the word (**mar**iquita, **mar**iachi, **mar**ica,...) has anything to do with transferring the unfair bad associations carried from one word to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being called a mariachi is like being called a clown for the way they dress mainly, not for the music. In countries like Argentina (I'm from here, don't really know about other countries) mariachi music is considered as a joke and funny. To sum up, "Ser [muy] mariachi" would be a friendly (not offensive) kind of insult (insult is not the word, I don't know how to express myself).

Comment: Maybe "teasing" is the word you're looking for; a mild sort of insult or playful "poking."

Comment: Yes! That's what I meant